# Query DbSet to dictionary with list

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table which I want to query so that it returns all values of a certain column mapped by a key that is another property (some ID).
for example:

```
class school {
    int SchoolType;
    Guid CountryID;
    string Name;
}
```

I want to get a dictionary where the key is the CountryID and the value is a list of all school names such that the school is of a certain type.

```
List<Guid, List<string>> mapCountryToSchools
```

Comment: List<T> has only one datatype. Maybe you want to use Dictionary<T, V>

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>` or you with LINQ you could use `ToLookup` and have it return a `ILookup`.

Comment: LINQ does not query databases.  Maybe you mean [tag:linq-to-sql] or [tag:entity-framework]?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using a GroupBy statement followed by a ToDictionary call, here is some example code.

```
// Simulating Database data
var America = Guid.NewGuid();
var Mexico = Guid.NewGuid();
var schools = new List<School>()
{
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School A", CountryID = America},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School B", CountryID = America},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School C", CountryID = America},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School E", CountryID = America},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School F", CountryID = Mexico},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School G", CountryID = Mexico},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School H", CountryID = Mexico},
    new School(){ SchoolType = 1, Name = "School I", CountryID = Mexico},
};
// Groups schools by their CountryID and then creates a dictionary
var mapCountryToSchools = schools.GroupBy(p => p.CountryID)
                                    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToList());
```